# Unable to executing multiple functions using multiprocessing module from a TKinter GUI

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Hi I have a small GUI which has a button using which two functions must be executed in different processors. In reality these two functions are heavy calculations. I do not want to use multi threading. I want them to run on 2 different processors. When I try to execute the button, another instance of the GUI gets created and it says

```
File "C:\Python3.7\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump. 
ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _tkinter.tkapp objects
```

My code is as follows.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from tkinter import Button, Tk, Frame

class GUI(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = Button(self, text="Start", command=self.execute)
        self.button.pack()
        self.pack()

    def F1(self):
        print("Hello")

    def F2(self):
        print("World")

    def execute(self):
        self.P1 = Process(target = self.F1)
        self.P2 = Process(target = self.F2)

        self.P1.start()
        self.P2.start()

        self.P1.join()
        self.P2.join()


Root = Tk()
Software = GUI()
Root.mainloop()
```

[Please click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56pRT.png)

Comment: Have you tried searching this site for `can't pickle _tkinter.tkapp objects`?

Comment: I have now understood that tkinter objects cannot be pickled, then it makes me wonder how massive calculations are executed using GUIs across several processors in HPCs?

Comment: All you need to do is make sure that none of tkinter code is in more than one process. The other processes can communicate with the tkinter thread using a queue.

Comment: I understand it, but in this situation I am multi processing any tkinter objects. Both the functions which are being multi processed are just printing functions. They do not have anything to do with Tkinter. I am sorry, I am beginner so can you explain in a detailed manner ?

Comment: The way your code is written, the code that creates the root window gets executed in both processes since it is in the global scope. Plus, the class that contains the functions is a Tkinter object, and it can't exist in multiple processes. The functions you run need to be outside the context of a tkinter object.

Comment: Can you please point me to an example, which does this ?

Comment: @BryanOakley, i agree with swaroop. I am also new to this as well. And we need more concrete examples. On my end, just want to ask a follow up question on your second comment. How can I put the tkinter GUI as separate process then the functions within as separate processes. So far, all the examples I have seen are just more on iterations. Or there are many functions to run via multiprocessing. But until now, I still dont understand that GUI part of multiprocessing. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

The problem lies with pickling tkinter widgets. You simply cannot do it, as the Tcl interpreter does not understand the python pickle format.

Coming to your code, I tried the following and it prints as expected:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from tkinter import Button, Tk, Frame

class GUI(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = Button(self, text="Start", command=self.execute)
        self.button.pack()
        self.pack()

    @staticmethod
    def F1():
        print("Hello")

    @staticmethod
    def F2():
        print("World")

    def execute(self):
        self.P1 = Process(target = GUI.F1())
        self.P2 = Process(target = GUI.F2())

        self.P1.start()
        self.P2.start()

        self.P1.join()
        self.P2.join()


Root = Tk()
Software = GUI()
Root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried your technique, it runs the code but it does not give result I wanted. It still creates multiple instances of the GUI. I am just starting to learn multi processing modules, so I am still in the exploring phase.

Comment: @SwaroopMajipatti The code above does indeed print _Hello_ and _World_ in two different lines without creating multiple instances of the GUI. I wonder if you added something else to your code

Comment: Sadly it does create multiple instances of the GUI                                                                  [Please click here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/56pRT.png

Comment: This code doesn't do what you think it does -- F1 and F2 are not run in a separate process. You're running them immediately and giving the results of the call (`None`)  as the value of `target`.

Comment: @BryanOakley, so how fix it? I am also following this. This might be the solution to my problem as well. Thank you.